# python 3.x: which is more efficient: list of lists vs. dict?

Tags: python-3.x, performance

Imaging you are doing a BFS over a grid (e.g. shortest distance between two cells). Two data structures can be used to host the `visited` info:

1) List of lists, i.e. `data = [[False for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]`. Later we can access the data in a certain cell by `data[r][c]`.

2) Dict, i.e. `data = dict()`. Later we can access the data in a certain cell by `data[(r, c)]`.

My question is: which is computationally more efficient in such BFS scenario?

Coding wise it seems the dict approach saves more characters/lines. Memory wise the dict approach can potentially save some space for untouched cells, but can also waste some space for hashtable's extra space.

**EDIT**

@Peteris mentioned numpy arrays. The advantage over list of lists is obvious: numpy arrays operate on continuous blocks of memory, which allow faster addressing and more cache hits. However I'm not sure how they compare to hashtables (i.e. `dict`). If the algorithm touches relatively small number of elements, hashtables might provide more cache hits given it's potentially smaller memory footprint.

Also, the truth is that numpy arrays are unavailable to me. So I really need to compare list of lists against dict.

Comment: Will your data size at any point grow/shrink or the data size will remain the same?

Answer (score 2):

### A 2D array

The efficient answer to storing 2D data is 2D arrays/matrixes allocated into a continuous area of memory (not like a list of lists). This avoids the multiple memory lookups required otherwise, and the calculation of a hash value at every lookup that's needed for a dict.

The standard way to do this in python is with the numpy library, here's a simple example

```
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros( (100, 200) ) # create a 100x200 array and initialize it with zeroes
data[10,20] = 1  # set element at coordinates 10,20 to 1
```

Comment: Thanks Peteris. I'm aware of numpy arrays. Yet it's not one of the options available to me, hence I only asked about native data structures. I guess I owe everyone that context, which I will add into my question.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me that a numpy array will *always* be faster than a hashtable, considering that a hashtable might have smaller foot print depending on the number of elements touched in the BFS process which can lead to more cache hits.